# how do I approach forecasting problems using deep neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, regression, normalization, forecasting

I am new to machine learning in general, and I have been requested to predict a price given a date. I have been trying to make a neural network for the task but it does poorly in the testing set, so I was hoping for some advice.

the data consists of 300 entries of a string date (YYYY-MM-DD) and the corresponding price starting from 1922.

here is what the price curve looks like:
[image: approach]

I had to find a way to featurize the dates somehow so here is what I came up with:

```
data = pd.read_csv("DataSet", header=0)
dates = pd.to_datetime(data["date"])

# the ratio of the current day of the year to the maximum number of days a year can have
dayOfYear = np.array(dates.dt.dayofyear).reshape(1, -1) / 366

# the ratio of the current week of the year to the maximum number of weeks a year can have
weeks = np.array(dates.dt.week).reshape(1, -1) / 52

# the ratio of the current month of the year to the maximum number of months a year can have
months = np.array(dates.dt.month).reshape(1, -1) / 12

# I wanted to squish the year to be between [0,1] so i shifted the tanh function to the right, 
# and divided it by a 100 just so I wouldn't end up with an array of mostly 1s. 
# I have no idea if that causes any issues or not, and Idid this based on nothing.
years = ac.tanh((np.array(dates.dt.year).reshape(1, -1) - 1922) / 100)

# the ratio of the current quarter of the year to the maximum number of quarters a year can have
quarter = np.array(dates.dt.quarter).reshape(1, -1) / 4

# the ratio of the current day of the week to the maximum number of days a week can have 
# (starting from 0).
weekDay = np.array(dates.dt.dayofweek).reshape(1, -1) / 6

# did the same thing I did with years. the number of days passed since the base date squished to [0,1],
# and the 10000 is there to delay convergence of the tanh function to 1.
# Again, I have no idea if any of this works since I had no upper bound to the data. 
delta = np.array((dates - pd.Timestamp('1922-3-31'))).reshape(1, -1)
daysSince = ac.tanh(delta / (np.timedelta64(1, 'D') * 10000))
```

that's the best I could think of when I tried extracting features from dates.
after that randomized the data, and took the last 50 examples of the 300 to be the validation set.

As for the network, I tried multiple configurations and after hours of trial and error, a 5 hidden layer network is what worked best with me.
the number of neuron along with their activation functions (including the output layer):

```
[256    ,128   , 110.   ,42.    , 18.  ,      1]        
["swish","tanh", "swish","swish","relu", "relu"]
```

I had to include activations other than `relu` because a mostly `relu` network kept calculating linear functions.

I have tried multiple loss functions, and I ended up using the MSE loss function.

I used a learning rate of 0.02 and a learning rate decay coefficient of 0.003273. the learning create decay function is as follows:

```
learning_rate / (1 + i * learning_rate_decay)
```

I also used mini batch gradient descent with a mini batch size of 32 and and Adam as an optimizer, and I train the network for 4600 epochs.

with this configuration I get an accuracy of 83% on the training set and 32% on the validation set (any prediction within 5 units of the expected output value is considered = ) .

here is the training set predictions vs the actual values:
[image]

the validation set predictions vs the actual values: 
[image]

and the cost function(MSE) change per 100 epochs:
[image]

obviously there are tons of mistakes in this network and I just want to know what am I doing wrong, and can this architecture work or is it unfit for such problems.

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly separating the training data and the validation data and not accidentally training on the validation as well. The validation curve prediction vs actual values you have looks too good to be true enough to warrant suspicion that something else might be happening.

Comment: Can it be because the validation set is basically random values taken from the data? So they can be viewed as just holes in the data that the network has o fill?

Comment: Oh yes that will definitely make it look way better than it actually this. As a simple test plot the answer to those validation points by just averaging the next and previous point that your training set contains. What you're doing is heavily overfitting, I would suggest looking at how to properly create a validation set from a time series (which is what you have).